# Priority queue where values are a sum of two currencies and popMin takes an exchange rate

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, priority-queue, kdtree

I want to define a priority queue where priorities have components in two different currencies. For example, Item A costs 1 USD + 20 yen. This queue has two methods, `insert(priceInUsd, priceInYen)` and `popMin(exchangeRate)`, which takes a price of a US dollar in yen, and pops the item with the lowest total cost in USD and yen given this exchange rate. How do I implement this?

Here are my ideas so far:

- Use a k-d tree. Insertion takes log(n). I think you can implement findMin by a minor modification to the normal k-d tree nearest-neighbor algorithm, so this should allegedly take log(n) time. Wikipedia is kind of hedgey about whether k-d tree nearest-neighbour is really log(n) worst case if you have terrible data, so I'm not sure about this. Also, I've never seen a particularly reliable-looking source claim that kd-trees allow log(n) insertion.
- Maintain the convex hull of the points, and loop over everything in it when you want to getMin. Worst case n, but if there are only normally `n**(1/3)` things in your convex hull, this is alright on average.

Comment: Please be more specific, what your sorting criteria are... `popMin(exchangeRate)` would suggest, that you want to get the minimum (by what standard?) for a given exchange rate.

Comment: I want to get the cheapest item by total cost; you use the exchange rate to convert the pair of values into a single cost.

Comment: For a dynamic exchange rate, there is a set of items that can't be ordered: for `Item1(dollar, yen)` and `Item2(dollar, yen)`, their value order can change depending on the exchange rate, if `sign(Item1.dollar - Item2.dollar) != sign(Item1.yen - Item2.yen)` Maybe that helps in sorting out possible solutions

Comment: Is there an upper bound to the possible price values? That would help for any quadtree-like solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some prior art that you didn't mention, on the [dynamic planar convex hull](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/P12.html) problem. [Brodal and Jacob](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall03/cs528/handouts/dynamic%20planar%20convex%20hull.pdf) (FOCS '02) give a data structure that lets you insert a point, delete a point, and find the extreme point in a direction in amortized logarithmic time, which suffices to implement your data structure (though the implementation looks complicated).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple answer that provides O(√n)-time inserts and O(√n log n)-time pop-mins.

Points are kept in one of O(√n) bins. Each bin has a convex hull computed for it, stored in order of `atan2(yen, usd)` (though you don't need trig to compare two points). The filling order for inserts is like this:

```
Bin 0:  0  2  5  9 14
Bin 1:  1  4  8 13
Bin 2:  3  7 12
Bin 3:  6 11
Bin 4: 10
...
```

To insert a point, assign it a bin and recompute the convex hull for that bin. This is O(√n)-time if you keep the points in sorted order of angle in an array and rerun a Graham scan.

To pop-min, we find the point to be deleted, delete it, and replace it with a point from another bin so as to maintain the right set of bin sizes (after an insertion, this is the bin that was just inserted into). The interesting part of this operation is the finding. To find the min total value for a given exchange rate on the convex hull, use binary search to find the predecessor and successor on the hull in terms of angle order, then return the min of those two.